# Tornado get_secure_cookie() returning value intermittently

Tags: python-2.7, session-cookies, tornado

Having trouble with redirect using get_secure_cookie() in tornado.

It seems the get_current_user() method is being called multiple times and intermittently finding data available via `self.get_secure_cookie("userid")`.

The following code let's me visit protected pages after logging in, but won't properly redirect:

```
class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get_current_user(self):
        username, self._user_perms = database.get_user_info(int(self.get_secure_cookie("userid") or 0))
        log.warning("WE HAVE A USERID %r and username: %r", self.get_secure_cookie("userid"), username)
        if self._user_perms: return username # If perms==0, the user has been banned, and should be treated as not-logged-in.
```

And in the output log:

```
2015-02-24 14:37:36,399:WARNING:__main__:WE HAVE A USERID None and username: None
2015-02-24 14:37:36,412:WARNING:__main__:WE HAVE A USERID None and username: None
2015-02-24 14:37:36,412:WARNING:__main__:WE GO:  u'/submit' AS None
2015-02-24 14:37:36,413:WARNING:__main__:WE HAVE A USERID None and username: None
2015-02-24 14:37:36,425:WARNING:__main__:WE HAVE A USERID None and username: None
2015-02-24 14:37:38,723:WARNING:__main__:WE HAVE A USERID '2' and username: u'My Name'
```

The login class is as follows:

```
class Login(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        form = UserForm()
        username = self.get_current_user()
        if self.get_current_user():
            self.redirect(self.get_argument('next', '/')) # Change this line
            return
        else:
            self.write(templates.load("login.html").generate(compiled=compiled, form=form, \
                                errormessage=errormessage, user_name=self.current_user))

    def post(self):
        form = UserForm(self.request.arguments)
        if form.validate():
            user_id = database.verify_user(self.get_argument('email'),\
                                self.get_argument('password'))
            if user_id:
                user_name, perms = database.get_user_info(user_id)
                if perms: self.set_secure_cookie("userid", str(user_id)) 
                self.redirect(self.get_argument("next", "/"))
            else:
                notice = "LOGIN FAILED. PLEASE TRY AGAIN."
                self.write(templates.load("login.html").generate(compiled=compiled, form=form, \
                                        notice=notice, user_name=self.current_user ))
        else:
            self.set_status(400)
            self.write(form.errors)
```

I thought maybe it was taking some time for the secure_cookie to become accessible and tried throwing a `time.sleep(2)` in there with the same (much slower) result.

What am I not seeing yet?

UPDATE:

As explained below, what ended up doing the trick was:

In `templates/login.html`:

```
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
```

In the `tornado app`:

```
#within the Login(BaseHandler) class
self.write(templates.load("login.html").generate(compiled=compiled, form=form, next=self.get_argument('next', "/"),
                        errormessage=errormessage, user_name=self.current_user, notice=notice ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the 'next' parameter isn't getting passed through the form. You'll need to pass that to the login.html form, and then pass it back, eg with a hidden input element. It'll then be available in the POST endpoint.